# Dynamic Range copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table and I want to copy the range between the cell that says `Row Labels` and the cell that says `Grand total`. Since the number of cells in between may vary depending on the underlying data, I need the copy to be dynamic.

Hence, I need to copy the range between `N7` and the cell before `Grand total`. I've done a screenshot of my screen:

[image]

The destination of the copy is to be copied over to cell `C11`.

Thanks to Chris Neilsen, I have end up with a code which unfortunately does not work, error:

> Application-defined or object-defined error [1004].

I understand the code and what it does, but I do not know why the error appears.

I would be tremendously thankful for any help given.

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("New Template")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("N7:N" & LastRow - 1).Select

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Make sure to change the table name accordingly, either in the code or the table. Can be found on the table design tab(visible when a cell within the table is selected)

```
Sub TransferListValues()
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        [C11].Resize(.ListRows.Count).Value = .ListColumns(1).Range.Offset(1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name").DataRange.Select
```

So you Need to change the:

- Pivot Table Name
- Activesheet
- Field Name

As nothing is Mentioned in the Question, I gave a General Case. Hope it Helps.